# Delegate twice within 2 class or call each other function in 2 class

Tags: objective-c, function, class, delegates

Basically, I want to call function from one class to another.I know I need to do delegate. 
However, for example, there is class A  and B. I need to call function in class A from class B and I also need to call function in class B from class A.

As a result, I need to import like

```
import "classA.h"  //to do in class B
import "classB.h"  //to do in class A

//then i may have delegate like this in both class
@protocol emailingroupViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)updateGroupEmail :(NSString *)inputKey;
@end
```

The problem is that it didn't allow me to import like this in between two class. How should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You have a dependency cycle in your headers.  It's easy to work around; instead of including the other class' header file in each header, you use the `@class` directive and include the header file in the implementation file.

In `classA.h`, do this:

```
@class ClassB

@interface ClassA

...

@end
```

In `classA.m`, do this:

```
#import "classA.h"
#import "classB.h"

@implementation ClassA : NSObject

...

@end
```

In `classB.h`, do this:

```
@class ClassA

@interface ClassB

...

@end
```

Finally, in `classB.m`, do this:

```
#import "classB.h"
#import "classA.h"

@implementation ClassB : NSObject

...

@end
```

---

However, if you're trying to use the delegate pattern, your delegate should implement a protocol rather than be an explicit class.  You should set up the connection between the delegate and the object that uses it in a third class.  This would be the header for ClassA:

```
@protocol SomeDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)classA:(ClassA *)classA didSomethingWithAString:(NSString *)string;

@end

@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SomeDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

---

However, again, if what you're trying to do is just have ClassA call a function in ClassB, which can call a function in ClassA, you might want to re-examine the way you've designed your classes.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. I am trying to call function between uiviewcontroller and uitableviewcontroller.  I need to import due to some reason like in this pictuer. However, when I import in to each other class, I got error like this. http://i43.tinypic.com/dwb212.png. I don't know what to do already. I need better code writing and design.